# Is this a bug in python 2 functions?

Tags: python, args

So I created a transpose function that has an option of adding column headers and I believe I came across a bug in python and using *args:

```
>>> def transpose(*args,header=None):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def transpose(*args,header=None):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so yes, since *args is for an arbitrary number of values, you can't put anything after it, **but** you should be able to put `variable=value` because then that variable has an automatic assignment making it separate from *args since you would call it with `header=['col1','col2','col3']` etc.

The following will not make an error:

```
def transpose(header=None,*args):
    #code goes here
```

The only issue with this is that this makes the first input to the function be assigned to the header without needing to do `header=value`, making `header` a required input, which is not what I want and I am sure not what many people who create functions using an arbitrary number of values want.

**With this error it makes it seem impossible to have a function that uses `*args` and have inputs that are not requirements. Is this a bug in python?**

note: I am using python2.7, so it very well could only be a bug in that version if it is a bug

Comment: how does my function not make sense? It takes a bunch of arrays and zips them together and if there is a list for headers it will then put that at index[0] for the list.

Comment: I have python 3, I am creating a module and I tested it in 2.7 because I want it to work in both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short python 2.x answer is "don't do that". :-)  (As @Bakurui noted it's built in to Python 3.x.)

If you really want to do that anyway, here's how (just the args part):

```
def transpose(*args, **kwargs):
    header = kwargs.pop('header', None)
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError('unexpected keyword args to transpose()')
    print 'transpose: args:', args
    print 'transpose: header:', header
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 2 the are no keyword only arguments. All arguments are positional and you may assign a default value to them. This means that for *any* function, you must be able to specify *any* argument using only positional arguments. In your definition you cannot give a value to `header` since `*args` consumes all the positional arguments, hence it is not a valid function definition.

In python3 there *are* keyword only arguments:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:57) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def transpose(*args, header=None): pass
... 
>>>
```

Note that you can also do:

```
>>> def transpose(*args, header): pass
... 
>>> transpose(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: transpose() needs keyword-only argument header
```

As you can see this is not a matter of having a default value or not. The syntax and semantics has changed with python3.

Comment: So basically what I want to do is only possible in python 3? That's frustrating, so no matter what, there is no way to use `*args` as well as a variable without a required input in python 2?

Comment: @RyanSaxe You can do whatever you want in python2, it's simply harder. For example you can have all functions accept `*args, **kwargs` and parse the arguments yourself.